# How to use Spring Security to check user login using an attribute in session?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot API application which require users to login in order to consume the API.

The login step is an API say **/api/login** is publicly accessible and once user called this API and authenticated, an HTTP session is created with the name "USER_PROFILE" and an object containing user info and stored in the session

`session.setAttribute("USER_PROFILE", userProfile)`.

What I want to do is to integrate with Spring Security, API other than **/api/login** Spring Security will automatically check if the session "USER_PROFILE" has existed in the session and if no, a 403 error will be returned.

Traditionally (without spring security) I will just create a web filter for the path **"/api/*"** and the filter will check the session. I am not sure for same logic using Spring Boot Security what is the best way to do so?

Comment: Basically your `/api/login` is working around Spring Security instead integrate that into Spring Security and it will simply work. Assuming you are using a Spring MVC controller you want to use a `Filter` for that and make that part of the Spring Security filter chain, that way it will simply work. Also there is no Spring Boot Security as that is just Spring Security.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the spring security filter chain and corrected the name :)